# Gif from external video

Tags: php, html

I have a list of video thumbnail and I want, when `onmouseover`, succeed in watching some images of the video
This is the code:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2w5tmFmifnDUkpHRmZ4VEJ1Rzg" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="700" height="430" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true">
```

Comment: Did you mean to put different tags in this?

Comment: No, I want to create a gif from this link above

Comment: What I meant was it's impossible to do this with pure PHP, it doesn't even make sense to mention mouse over events in the context of PHP. HTML is also not appropriate for this. Did you mean to ask this in the context of JavaScript?